# 'Accordion' style panels - retain position of clicked element relative to the browser window

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I've run into a small usability issue, and I can't get my head around the solution.

[image: image of panel states]

Imagine 1 [above] as being a set of large divs, say the width of a typical web page e.g. 900px.

A user can click on a div to expand it, for example in [2] the first div has been clicked.

In [3] the second div has been clicked, opening it and also closing the first one.

The trouble is that the top of this newly opened div 'moves up' from it's position at [2]. This is normal and expected behaviour of course, but in my specific application with lots of similar, large divs it is confusing for the user; the point of focus for the user is no longer where it was.

**Ideally, what I want is behaviour like [4], where the clicked element will remain in the same place relative to the browser window.**

Obviously this requires that the page has been scrolled down a bit to allow the page to 'move down' to compensate. This should *usually* be the case as the user will have scrolled down a bit to see these divs.

Hopefully this makes sense...

J

Comment: From a usability standpoint, I would suggest a different solution: rather that adding extra space to the page, create a scroll event that resets the viewport to the top of the newly opened div. Would this work? The end result would be that the user would still be looking at the top of the opened div.

Comment: I don't understand how the div could remain in the same place, unless you shift the rest of the page down.  Is that what you mean?  I don't see the examples, btw.

Comment: @robooneus -  I was a bit unclear about the extra space - I meant merely that the page would need to have been scrolled down a bit already as this functionality would require that to work. Your idea to have the top of the div set to the viewport may be an alternative approach to consider.

Comment: @jegesh - Yes that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: @james6848 Yes, I understood the bit about the extra space, but the end result would be the same regardless of the approach. Rather than adding extra space so that the item stays in the same position, use a scroll event so that, to the user, the view is of the same position. Or perhaps this doesn't fit the usage you have in mind.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to you to just add a line of code that jumps you to an anchor at the head of the div clicked on?  Then the opened div wouldn't remain in its same relative position on the screen, but it would always appear at the top of the screen.

Comment: @robooneus - Ah OK I see what you mean now. Yes - any approach will do.

Comment: @jegesh - This would be an OK Plan B if I can't find another solution to keep it exactly where it is.

Comment: The best solution would most likely use the `offset()` method of the clicked div (or its header) and the `scrollTop()` method of the document to calculate the exact position of the header in the viewport, and then use that calculation to reset the viewport after the accordion event.  The part I don't understand is how to fire the re-positioning only after the accordion event has concluded.

Comment: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/4K4Uj/) a fiddle that I wrote up to do the getting part of the position.

Comment: I now realized that the best way to do this would probably be to edit the `accordion` object [code](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js), inserting three lines at the beginning of the `onclick` event to get the position data, and one more line at the end in order to reset the viewport.  I was unable to figure out where to insert these lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working solution, applying an `accordion` jQuery IU object:

(assuming the containing `div` is and `accordion` object with `id` 'accordion')

```
$("#accordion").on("accordionbeforeactivate", function (event, ui) {
    var pos = $(ui.newHeader).offset().top;// get current position of div being opened
    var view_pos = $(document).scrollTop();// get relative position on screen
    delta = pos - view_pos;// var not declared in order to make it available to other function
    });
$("#accordion").on("accordionactivate", function (event, ui) {
    var newPos = $(ui.newHeader).offset().top;
    $(document).scrollTop(newPos-delta );// reposition to same relative place on screen
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4K4Uj/1/)

Link to documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate

Comment: Many thanks, I have been able to do this using your offset() and scrollTop() ideas.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#accordian h3").click(function(){
           //slide up all the link lists
          $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
          //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
           if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
        {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        }
```

For more details [**click here**](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/vertical-accordion-menu-using-jquery-css3)

Comment: The div clicked does not always remain in the same position in relation to the screen with your solution--it depends on its order in the list and which other div is already open.  This is just the standard jQueryUI Accordion widget.